# Why was my question about whether or not C/C++ behaviour undefined downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, scope

I recently posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783816/why-does-a-c-pointer-to-char-act-as-a-character-string-despite-the-lack-of-a-n) about C/C++ and undefined behavior. It was downvoted significantly (to me at least).

This tells me that I did something wrong but I'm not sure what it was -- all I did is ask if behavior is undefined and for more details about why it was behaving if it was. This seems to be on-topic as it is about writing software and having a better understanding of C++.

What can I do with future questions (and possibly to edit my exiting question as well) to ensure that they are better received and don't have whatever issue my current question does?

Comment: SO users tend to greatly over-estimate their ability to create Q+A that's a useful addition to the body of knowledge that SO maintains.  It is at best a forum question.  You could post it to Yahoo Answers for example and somebody could actually answer "Because of UB".  Nobody can post answers like that at SO.  Research your questions first and mishaps like this are much less likely.

Comment: I believe it is seeking for question specific improvements instead of general reason of downvoting only